# C# Windows Listview Scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

In windows forms ,how can I bring the default scroll bar inside the listview.

Please refer image attached.[image]

Comment: Might want to add a little more guts to your question, if you want an accurate answer.  Your current question almost looks like a statement.

Comment: Are you asking how to *re-create* what's shown in the image you posted? Or do you want to *change* what's shown in the image?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try

```
listView.Scrollable = true;
```

?

Comment: Need horizantal scroll bar for listview of just 1 column, when item/data inside listview exceeds listview capacity(width)....need to display scroll bar.   plz help if u got some idea